# Batch Restart Java.exe

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

Java.exe often crashes or is unresponsive when using the Filemaker Console.

We need to kill the process and start it again manually in order to make it work properly again.

I found that I can use the command `taskkill /im java.exe /F` to kill it, but I can't seem to start it again with the batch file.
I will change directory to `Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\`, then I will type `java.exe`, it shows me all the switches as if i type `java.exe /?`

But if I do a search in Windows, I see java.exe as being the result, and I click it with my mouse, it starts correctly..

How can I start java.exe correctly with the command line please

What are the correct switches to start java.exe from command line?

Comment: You don't just start java.exe without parameters. java.exe is used to start an application via a class' main method. If you call it without parameters, then it will simply advise you of the executable's usage and parameters. You will need to call java.exe again using the same parameters that it was called with previously. You can't cd to an exe file BTW.

Comment: What do you mean by `cd\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe`? That does not look like a valid command unless you meant `c:\Program...`

Comment: I meant cd\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin
then java.exe on another line

Comment: cd will only change to that directory. It won't start java.exe. You'll need a separate batch command for that, passing in the appropriate parameters that it was initially called with.

Comment: Yes I am sorry it is what I meant,
So I changed directory to c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin
but when I type java.exe in that directory

I does not start java.exe, it shows me the list of triggers as if I typed java /?

So what are the switches I need to add to java.exe to start it just normally

Comment: "*But if I do a search in Windows, I see java.exe as being the result, and I click it with my mouse, it starts correctly..*" - that doesn't jive. Has someone edited the shortcut to change the parameters but still named it "java.exe"? Look at the shortcut properties and look at the full 'target' string including parameters. You'll need to pass all those to Java.

Comment: If you did not initiate the call to java, and you don't know the parameters, then you won't be able to restart it correctly. If you have the shortcut there and it starts fine, then you can get the correct parameters from the shortcut.

Comment: Made a little video to make it easier to understand
http://screencast.com/t/duj0O1Aj4

Comment: note that your task kill command does not guarantee it's targeting the right java.exe JVM process. If you're running multiple java applications, this command could in fact kill completely the wrong thing, and then start a second instance of the thing you were actually trying to kill. Read through https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb491009.aspx to come up with a better line.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but everytime I did kill it, there was only one process running. This server is dedicated to be a filemaker server and thats it.

So what I am really looking for basically, is how to start java.exe from the commandline, or what are the switches I need to add for it start from there

Comment: @user5442433 You need the path to the application you want to run (Filemaker Console?). The command would be something like `java.exe <C:\....\filemaker.exe`.

Comment: Actually when I do it manually.
CTRL-ALT-DEL
JAVA.exe Terminate process
I search windows, java and click on java.exe
Thats it

screencast.com/t/duj0O1Aj4

Comment: You should not be killing a java process that was not initiated by you. If you can find what starts the java process and check its parameters, then you could restart it using the same parameters, but you really need to figure out the key problem here: why is it hanging in the first place, rather than killing and recreating the process.